# Any differce between mvn:assembly and mvn:package

Tags: build, jar, maven-2, war

I knew `mvn:package` can be used to generate JAR or WAR, is there any difference between `mvn:assembly`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are quite different. 'package' is a simple command used for simple/single projects where you only have to create a jar/war.

The [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) is much more powerful, and can be used to create full distribution packages for large projects. This can be just a simple jar file, but it can also be a large distribution archive for your project, including source code, documentation, etc. You configure what the assembly should look like by means of an XML file called the assembly descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly is needed if you plan to create an archive that contains your classes plus the libraries + docs + ...

To create war (or any native Maven packaging) you can simply set `<packaging>war</packaging>`.
If you want to customize this war, you need the war (respectivelly jar) plugin.